# VBScript to uninstall a Windows 7 application

Tags: vbscript, wmi, uninstallation

I am attempting to write a script that will uninstall a program when it is run.  The problem is that the program will not have the exact same name each time, as it will have a version number attached.  Is there anyway to grab the program name from a list, assuming it contains what I'm looking for?  Then use that name to finish the uninstall?

The only uninstall function that I've found is:

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Product Where Name = 'Personnel database'") 

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware 
    objSoftware.Uninstall() 
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) operator instead of `=` in your query to test the product name against a pattern, like this:

```
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Product Where Name LIKE '%Personnel database%'")
```